# Creating a session key pool in Mule

Tags: mule

I have a Mule app that calls an external web service. Before calling this web service I must call a session key web service to retrieve a session key to send to the orignal target web service. This session key service takes as input the same company name parameter as a login each time and returns a unique string each time its invoked which is valid for 10 minutes. A unique key must be used per web service call and no two can be used at the same time.

So these session keys cant be keyed by anything because theres only 1 login but multiple different session keys for that 1 login.

I have been looking at Apache Commons Pool for this, more specifically - GenericObjectPool that doesn't required each session key to be keyed which works well.

But Im struggling to integrate this with Mule in a nice way. I have set this up using Spring and the interfaces i have to implement dictate that I put all my http requests and transformations etc. to contact the external web services within the Java code. But ideally i want to use Mules core transports and transformers for this.

WHat is the best way to architect this?

Create an interceptor?

Inject the transports into my custom code?

Or is there a better way to do simple non-keyed pooling that fits better with Mule?

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your pool object factory use Mule transports directly or interact with your flows via the [MuleClient](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/client/MuleClient.html).

If you make the Spring bean [MuleContextAware](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/MuleContextAware.html), you'll receive a [MuleContext](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/MuleContext.html) from which you'll get a Mule client with `getClient()`.

Comment: Thank for the response David. im not sure I follow. I don't need to invoke methods of my java class from my flows. It's actually the other way around: I need to call Mule endpoints or transformers from my Java code to populate the session key pool and update the pool when keys expire etc. If that makes sense?

Comment: Gotcha, reviewed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have actually been reading your book and was concerned about coupling my components with Mule's internals. Is the MuleClient/MuleContextAware the best of the "bad"?